# Best way to handle configurable static links with Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I'd like to be able to have a way of pulling in a URL prefix from a properties file or the like for references to static resources in Thymeleaf, so that I can, e.g., have a file url for development and a reference to, e.g., static.cdn.com Having a variable added to every page's context is too much repetition. Is there some approach short of creating a dialect so that I can have a configurable attribute?

Comment: Have you tried `mvc:resources` tag in your spring config.?

Comment: That solves a different problem. mvc:resources maps a server URL to a static resource directory.